# Lessthan symbol automatically converted to "& lt ;" when passed to JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to find a reason for this.

I have created a Spring MVC project. 
A map "conMap" is set in model attribute having values <34, >=34.

```
model.addAttribute("conMap", conMap);
```

In JSP, dropdown is being populated like this

```
<form:select path="settings.con" items="${conMap}" class="dropdwn" />
```

While doing view page source in browser, I found that lessthan symbol is replaced by "& lt ;" and so on. 
But if I am creating a normal dropdown(not spring form:select) and populating the values in forEach loop from the same map, lessthan symbol is not replaced by "& lt ;"

Can anyone help me in finding the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the html tags , add the attribute `htmlEscape="true"` to the spring `<form:select>` tag. And

```
<form:select path="settings.con" items="${conMap}" class="dropdwn" htmlEscape="true" />
```

[Read more..](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-html-escape-and-escape-body-tags-springhtmlescape-and-springescapebody/)